# What is exports.install in node js?

Tags: node.js

Hi I found a [framework](https://github.com/totaljs/examples/blob/master/contact-form/controllers/default.js) where they use a lot this pattern.

```
exports.install = function(){
//code
}
```

but usually you see this pattern in nodejs

```
module.exports = {
//code
}
```

Is this the same thing or is this something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exports` is the object corresponding to `module.exports` before you do anything to it.  I think it's due to some legacy code, but basically folks use `module.exports` if they want to replace the whole object with their own object or a function, while they use `exports` if they just want to hang functions off the module.  It's a little confusing at first, but essentially `exports.install` just means that calling code would do something like:

```
const mod = require('that-module');
mod.install(params, callback); // call that function
```

The framework you're looking at is probably using it as part of a bootstrapping process, afaik it doesn't have significance to the node engine itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the same thing. You can use one of 2 ways to setup your code.

The different thing is `memory`. They point to same memory. You can think `exports` like a variable and you can not use this way to export your module:

Given this module:

```
// test.js
exports = {
    // you can not use this way to export module.
    // because at this time, `exports` points to another memory region
    // and it did not lie on same memory with `module.exports`
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log("Hello !");
    }
}
```

The following code will get the error: `TypeError: test.sayHello is not a function`

```
// app.js
var test = require("./test");
test.sayHello();
// You will get TypeError: test.sayHello is not a function
```

The correct way you must use `module.exports` to export your module:

```
// test.js
module.exports = {
    // you can not use this way to export module.
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log("Hello !");
    }
}

// app.js
var test = require("./test");
test.sayHello();
// Console prints: Hello !
```

So, it just is style of developer.